# Traefik v2 and Odoo: Update container hosts without restart

Tags: docker-compose, odoo, traefik

In my env, I use Traefik as a proxy and SSL provider to expose Odoo containers.

I have to choose between two possible arch:

1. Currently, I have an Odoo container for each database.

- Bring up/down a database without disturbing other instances
- Set traefik host rule in docker-compose and you have an https/letsencrypt route
- You can't just give the odoo instances all possible workers and let it manage them. You have to give a certain number of them to each instance and monitor if you are under/over performing

2. Have only one Odoo container serving all databases filtered per domain

- Updating the sources and monitoring is much easier
- Give your instance all possible workers, it will always perform as good as possible.
- I have to shutdown the container to update the hosts rule when I have a new customer.

Maybe I'm not making an enlighted choice and I'm fully open to suggestions, but I would like to handle solution 2 but having to bring the container down just to had a new host...

So is it possible to add a new host and trigger the letsencrypt generation without restarting the container ?